# Which control supports templates?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, asp.net-controls

I've got a user control which can be rendered in several different ways depending on the value of one of the properties. For example:

The markup could be:

```
<h1><asp:Literal id="Title" runat="server" /></h1>
<asp:Literal id="Description" runat="server" />
```

Or it could be:

```
<div class="demo" id="box1">
<span><asp:Literal id="Title" runat="server" /></span>
<asp:Image id="LogoImage" runat="server" />
</div>
```

So the HTML could be very different. I could use a multiview which will allow me to do this, however the annoyance is that in each view I will have to add the literal called "Title" and create a different naming convention for it. Is there a control that supports templates which will allow me to add the literal "Title" to each template? That way in my code I only have to set the value of Title once....

Any ideas anyone?

Thanks in advance
Al

Answer (score 0):

Controls that implement the [`ITemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.itemplate.aspx) interface:

> Defines the behavior for populating a templated ASP.NET server control
>   with child controls. The child controls represent the inline templates
>   defined on the page.

You can create your own control with the desired template:

[How to: Create Templated ASP.NET User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36574bf6%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)